# Usercontrol not updated when value changes in codebehind

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have a viewmodel class that is update at runtime. However, if a value in the viewmodel is changed in the codebehind at runtime, the view is not updated. Where did I go wrong?

The viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class vmA : modelA, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName));
    }

    public vmA ()
    {
        SomeValue = 254.43F; //This value is shown when the control is loaded
    }

    public void SetSomeValue(int _someValue)
    {
        SomeValue = _someValue; // If this is executed, the view still shows 254.43, even though _someValue contains a different value
    }
}
```

The model (which is inherited by the viewmodel) class looks like this

```
public class modelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName));
    }

    private int someValue

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get { return someValue
        set { someValue value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeValue")); }                  
    }
}
```

The binding is done like this

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:vmA></vm:vmA>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The textbox binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbBetragNetto" Text='{Binding BetragNetto, Mode=TwoWay}' Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have 2 `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementations. The binding is getting confused with which `PropertyChanged` event you want it to listen to. Shrink your view model to this:

```
public class vmA : modelA
{
    public vmA()
    {
        SomeValue = 254.43F; //This value is shown when the control is loaded
    }

    public void SetSomeValue(int _someValue)
    {
        SomeValue = _someValue; // If this is executed, the view still shows 254.43, even though _someValue contains a different value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Will the view then be notified about changes in  the viewmodel, for example, if I add another property to the viewmodel?

Comment: Yes. Because the view model inherits from something that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it will also have that naturally.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine